# Focus Maps Analysis (Density Map)

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

I have different focus maps (RGB images) which I got by building the grads of a CNN classifier.

[image: RGB Focus map]

I want to make statistic analysis on these images.
Is there a possibility to calculate the covariance of these pictures and the center of mass?

Comment: Yes, you can use a bidimensional gaussian process, also known as kriging, to fit the data and obtain the covariance. Regarding the center of mass, I assume the color scale represents in this case the "mass". Then, you need to average (separately) the x and y coordinates of all your points, where the weight are the value of the color scale or mass associated with each point.